# How to send PDF file data as a response using Servlet?

Tags: java, ios, jakarta-ee, servlets

My requirement is responding the PDF data to the mobile client(iPhone) using HTTP Servlet.

I did in the following way, But I am not getting expected output in the client.

```
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String aInputFileName = "/Users/hcl/Desktop/Easwar/sample.pdf";
        log("Reading in binary file named : " + aInputFileName);
        File file = new File(aInputFileName);
        log("File size: " + file.length());
        byte[] result = new byte[(int)file.length()];
        System.out.println("Length : "+  result.length);
        try {
          InputStream input = null;
          try {
            int totalBytesRead = 0;
            input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            while(totalBytesRead < result.length){
              int bytesRemaining = result.length - totalBytesRead;
              //input.read() returns -1, 0, or more :
              int bytesRead = input.read(result, totalBytesRead, bytesRemaining); 
              if (bytesRead > 0){
                totalBytesRead = totalBytesRead + bytesRead;
              }
            }
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");

        out.println(result);
```

Is the method I am following right? Please advice.

Thanks.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot out is PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); Edited my question. Do you still say to use write(), if so how to do that.

Comment: Use `ServletOutputStream out` and you need to use `write()` on `out` .

Comment: @TheNewIdiot ServletOutputStream this works. Could you please mention the same in answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use [ServletOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletOutputStream.html) and its [write()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write%28byte%5b%5d%29) method to write bytes to the response .

Answer (score 6):

```
package com.javatpoint;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import com.darwinsys.spdf.PDF;
import com.darwinsys.spdf.Page;
import com.darwinsys.spdf.Text;
import com.darwinsys.spdf.MoveTo;

public class ServletPDF extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException {

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");

        response.setHeader("Content-disposition","inline; filename='javatpoint.pdf'");

        PDF p = new PDF(out);
        Page p1 = new Page(p);
        p1.add(new MoveTo(p, 200, 700));
        p1.add(new Text(p, "www.javatpoint.com"));
        p1.add(new Text(p, "by Sonoo Jaiswal"));

        p.add(p1);
        p.setAuthor("Ian F. Darwin");

        p.writePDF();
    }
}
```