# display pdf / download pdf from Oracle databse using spring and hibernate

Tags: web-services, hibernate, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have an object with field

```
@Column(name = "PDF")
@Lob @Basic(fetch=javax.persistence.FetchType.LAZY)
private byte[] pdf;
```

My dao retrieves this object succesfully using the enitity manager findbyid() method.

I want to display this pdf on browser or download the pdf when the request comes to my controller.

This is what i did.

```
@Autowired
DocDownloadService docService;
HttpServletResponse response;
@RequestMapping("/document/view/{docID}")
public String getAlert(@PathVariable("docID") String docId){
    docService.downloadDoc(docId, response);
    return null;
}
```

And my service

```
@Override
@Transactional
public String downloadDoc(String docId, HttpServletResponse response){

    MyDoc doc = this.getDocById(docId); //brings document object from my DAO

    try {
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=report.pdf");
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.getOutputStream().write(doc.getPdf(), 0, doc.getPdf().length);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return null;
}
```

I get a null pointer exception at the "response.addheaders line.. I am not sure why. I have looked through other posts and tried all those methods but it didnt help.
Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
@RequestMapping("/document/view/{docID}")
public String getAlert(@PathVariable("docID") String docId, HttpServletResponse response){
```

Also, it is better if you handle the response.outputstream within the controller rather than handling it at the service.

Comment: It worked but the file that got downloaded is corrupted.

Comment: I think you dont have to mention the lenght on the stream, try removing it

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977274/how-to-send-pdf-file-data-as-a-response-using-servlet 2nd answer