# JSP- How to view PDF documents when a JSP page is called?

Tags: jsp

I have a JSP page called `viewPDF.jsp` in my project.Inside this page, I would like it to be able to view PDF document depending on the nodeID which is document ID.So when I sent the URL in this format:

```
http://localhost:8080/repository/view/viewPDF.jsp?nodeID=27453
```

The other user is able to view this file(id=27453) in the browser in a PDF format. The nodeID varies depending on which file is being generated in URL.

In my JSP page, I thought of using this:

```
<embed src="file_name.pdf?" width="800px" height="2100px" />
```

But this is obviously hardcoded and I need it to be dynamic. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send PDF file data as a response using Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977274/how-to-send-pdf-file-data-as-a-response-using-servlet)

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala My question is different as in I need to get the value of nodeID passing to two JSP pages to I am able to construct viewPDF to load documents based on parameter

Comment: changing the document based on a parameter is another `if` statement. The idea of using _`ServletOutputStream` and its `write()` method to write bytes to the response_ stays same.